# MSBuild Starter Kits

Tags: .net, msbuild, package, msbuild-task, sample

Just wondering if anyone knows if there are any MSBuild starter kits out there.

What I mean by starter kits is that from the looks of it most builds to kinda the same sort of steps with minor changes here and there (i.e. most builds would run test, coverage, zip up the results, produce a report, deploy etc). Also what most people in general want from a CI build, test build, release build is mostly the same with minor changes here and there.

Now don't get me wrong i think that most scripts are fairly different in the end. But I can't help but think that most start out life being fairly similar.

Hence does anyone know of any "starter kits" that have like a dev/CI/test/release build with the common tasks that most people would want that you can just start changing and modifying?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out the MSBuild blog site. They got some stuff:
[Getting Started with MSBuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2010/02/25/getting-started-with-msbuild.aspx)

The MSBuild Extension Pack provides a collection of over 415 MSBuild Tasks, MSBuild Loggers and MSBuild TaskFactories.

Answer (score 1):

[PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=msbuild&highlight=david-starr_msbuild-1%2a1,3,4!david-starr_msbuild-5%2a5,4!david-starr_msbuild-2%2a6,7,8!david-starr_msbuild-3%2a1!david-starr_msbuild-4#msbuild-1) has a good video on the intro level course of MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

You can go first to this article: [Walkthrough: Using MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx) Really Usefull (in that article you can find a lot of link to more specific subjects related with MsBuild) ;)